# Missing app/uninstalled webhook - Shopify

Tags: shopify-app

I tried creating a webhook for `app/uninstalled` event.
However, I wasn't able to find it.

[image]

[image]
Can anyone guide me where exactly can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

The `app/uninstalled` webhook can only be registered through the [Webhooks API](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/webhook). Note that it will only fire when the app that registered the webhook is uninstalled. Other apps will not trigger it.